# SharePoint 2013 CSOM Upload Doc and Change Column Values

Tags: 2013, csom

I'd like to upload a document to a SharePoint 2013 document library and set value for three of the columns.

I'm running following C# code from a unit test within Visual Studio:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext($"{spRoot}/{spPathToFolder}"))
            {
                ctx.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, targetFileUrl, ms, true);

                var uploadedFile = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(targetFileUrl);
                var listItem = uploadedFile.ListItemAllFields;

                listItem["Title"] = "title";
                listItem["UPRN"] = "uprn";
                listItem["KeystoneDocType"] = "keystoneDocType";
                listItem.Update();
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

The following path variables values are logged:

```
spRoot=[https://collaboration.xxx.com], spPathToFolder=[sites/HousingICTSolution/Technical]

targetFileUrl=[/sites/HousingICTSolution/Technical/AssetMgmtEfilesDemo/xxxLogo_190213115512.png]
```

On executing the line "ctx.ExecuteQuery()" there's a delay of about 2 seconds before control returns to the debugger. There are no errors but there's no sign of the document within the library. Anyone see where I went wrong?

Comment: try to do ctx.Update() after SaveBinaryDirect()

Comment: it seems there is no Update method on the ClientContext object?

Comment: i mean ctx.ExecuteQuery() :D

Comment: I'm afraid that made no difference - no error but still no sign of the document appearing in the document library

Comment: so there'S problem with saving the file to sharepoint, cause you need to save it, after this you will update properties. try find another solution for saving document to SPO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an answer on SO, thanks to @Jerry_MSFT. I tweaked it a little, the following works ok:

```
public void UploadAndSetProps(string spRoot, string spPathToFolder, string spFolder, string spFilename, MemoryStream ms)
    {
        _log.WriteLine($"Entered UploadAndSetProps. spRoot=[{spRoot}], spPathToFolder=[{spPathToFolder}]");

        try
        {
            string targetFileUrl = $"/{spPathToFolder}/{spFolder}/{spFilename}";
            _log.WriteLine($"targetFileUrl=[{targetFileUrl}]");
            using (var ctx = new ClientContext($"{spRoot}/{spPathToFolder}"))
            {
                ctx.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                using (ms)
                {
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, targetFileUrl, ms, true);
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                }

                var uploadedFile = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(targetFileUrl);

                var listItem = uploadedFile.ListItemAllFields;
                listItem["Title"] = "title";
                listItem["UPRN"] = "uprn";
                listItem["KeystoneDocType"] = "keystoneDocType";
                listItem.Update();
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                listItem.File.CheckIn("Added by BizTalk", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.WriteException(ex);
            throw ex;
        }

        _log.WriteLine("Leaving UploadAndSetProps");


    }
```